# Should I worry when overriding function.toString in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, overloading

When I write function wrappers in JavaScript (for example: a `throttle` or `debounce` function), I would like to be able to inspect the 'decorated' function and still be able to know what is the underlying function. Take an implementation of `throttle` for an example:

```
function throttle(fn, time) {
  var handle;

  var execute = function() {
    handle = null;
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  var throttled = function() {
    if(!handle) {
      handle = setTimeout(execute.bind(this), time);
    }
  };

  throttled.toString = function() {
    return fn.toString() + "\n// throttled to " + time + "ms";
  };

  return throttled;
}

var makeAjax = throttle(function(callback) {
  $.getJSON("/path", callback);
}, 500);

console.log(makeAjax);
```

The `console.log` call displays:

```
function (callback) {
  $.getJSON("/path", callback);
}
// throttled to 500ms
```

As a user of `throttle` I care a whole lot more about the function I gave it than its internal `throttled`.

However, I always feel a little uneasy while overriding native functions. Are there any compliance and/or performance issues that I should worry about when doing this?

Comment: Implicit casting might be an issue. But you probably won't have cases where you'll implicitly cast a function.

Comment: Anything that would call `fn.toString()` is either for logging or dynamic recompliation so I think you will be fine for this. Especially because you are not overwriting `Function.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @Esailija what do you mean by dynamic recompilation?

Comment: @RenatoZannon read the function body via `.toString()`, modify it, and `eval` the result. It's not any kind of normal thing to do, so don't worry. It can be used for meta programming.

Answer (score 3):

In Mozilla Developer Group, they talk more about overriding toString().
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

I think what could be a possible issue here is creating the automated Unit-Test (my experience is limited to NUnit Selenium), you may not able to use the private .toString() or it might cause unstable test results? also debugging might be an issue!

For overriding other local js functions that has methods, you might need to manually extend all of the methods as well to replace what's been overriden.

Addy Osmani discusses this further in his book "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns", http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: The goal is to assist in debugging, since you can't normally get to the original function when dealing with a decorated one... I guess it could make bugs in `throttle` nastier to find though. I didn't understand what you mean in your third paragraph, can you expand a bit or give an example? Thanks!

Comment: The mdn article is about `Object.prototype.toString`, not [`Function.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString). The object toString is not relevant here at all.

Comment: @Esailija By default, functions in javascript are objects. So when you create a function, it automatically inherits Object properties. for further reading check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: @Esailija I think you will need to start a new thread for this comment, it's starting to go off-topic.

Comment: @RenatoZannon just for example, say you have this variable,
`var x = Math.min(12, 5).toString();`
if you were to override `Math.min()` function it will not automatically inherit `.toString()` as well, you will need to extend that manually.